# Prevent all devices from waking my computer

Tags: windows, wake-up

Sometimes when I bump my mouse or my keyboard my computer turns on. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can disable **all** devices from waking your computer with **`powershell -Command "powercfg /devicequery wake_armed | ForEach{ powercfg /devicedisablewake $_ }"`**.

In `cmd`, you can run `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` to get a list of the devices that are currently allowed to wake up your computer. Chances are you’ll see a couple HIDs (human interface device) and maybe a network card. You can copy/paste these into the corresponding command, `powercfg /devicedisablewake "your device here"`, but that’s annoying.

The `ForEach{ $_ }` operates a bit like [`xargs`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) if you’re familiar with that, where `$_` is a placeholder for the text in each line of the input (i.e. the `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` before the pipe).

Comment: While this works, the list gets repopulated on every reboot. Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: `powershell -Command "powercfg /devicequery wake_armed | ForEach{ powercfg /devicedisablewake $_ }"`
`Unable to perform operation.  An unexpected error (0x490) has occurred:  Element not found.`
Any clues?

Comment: Doesnt work here  `Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help` Windows wants to open up and use your internet when you sleep and that is why "Sleep" is a dumb function

Answer (score 2):

**Possible solution below**

This did not work for many users, including me:

```
powercfg /devicedisablewake "your device here"
```

There was some kind of admin rights problem even though we all ran the command line as administrators. Just did a search about this through the web today and there is massive amount of unresolved queries about it. Well, I think I might have resolved it. I had exactly opposite problem that the first question suggested, my device was actually preventing sleep of my monitor. So I did two things and at least one of them helped me:

A) I installed an old driver for the device that was causing problems (Genius MaxFire Blaze 5 gamepad controller) instead of the default one (MS driver for Xbox 360 controller from 2019 I think). Well, at least I tried to. I had to resort to updating it by "have disk" and manually pushing the old drivers to the system after I found them installed in the system.

**EDIT: it WAS a driver issue after all. The old gamepad driver was uninstalled after machine restart (because I installed the new one instead) and it broke the monitor sleep again. So I installed it back and hopefully I will never have this issue again.** The old driver is from 2009, the new one is from 2019. "Good job", Microsoft!

<s>B) at the same time I made a small hack file called **disable_wake_gamepad.cmd**, it's name does not matter. The content was the exact line that was not working for me in the shell:</s>

```
powercfg /devicedisablewake "HID-compliant game controller"
```

Next I have opened group policy editor **gpedit.msc** and navigated to `User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts > Logon` and added my little script by the **Add** button. Then I restarted machine because the script runs at logon (presumably under System credentials).

And I think this helped. I tried to reinstall back the newest MS driver for the gamepad and it did install back and the gamepad is STILL NOT blocking the monitor sleep, so success - after 2 days of research and testing various things.

* Note: HID-compliant game controller was the device name from the list (powercfg devicequery wake_armed) of wake_armed devices. I knew it's the gamepad that caused problems because when I disconnected it, the monitor was able to sleep**.

** It's easy to test monitor sleep quickly by using a small utility like for example DisplayPowerOff4.1 or the Nirsoft utility.

I will keep testing this and will update this post if I find out what exactly helped. But you guys now have good leads now. Good luck, you will need it. FYI this gamepad was FINE with my monitor under Win7, it's <s>Microsoft</s> Windows 10 that broke it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to disable it only for the mouse and keyboard do this:

1. Open the Device Manager
2. Navigate to Keyboards
3. Select and default/ using keyboard (usually Standard PS/2 Keyboard), right-click and go to properties
4. Tap Power-Management and uncheck “Allow this device to wake the computer”:
   [image]

**Same steps for the mouse!**

Note: This does not work on every device, on laptops there maybe you have to go to the Power Options!